# In Python, do I need to protect data transfer between multi-threaded processes?

Tags: python, multithreading

For example, if a process is generating an image, and other parallel process is accessing this image through a get method, my intuition tells me that it may be dangerous to access that image while it is being written.

In C++ I have to use mutexes to make sure the image isn't accessed while it is being written, otherwise I'm experiencing random segfaults. but since python has some data protection mechanisms that I don't fully know, I'm not sure if I need to do this.

```
PSEUDO-CODE:

Class Camera(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._capture = camera_handler() #camera_handler is a object that loads the driver and lets you control the camera.
        self.new_image = None
        self._is_to_run = False

    def start(self):
        self._is_to_run = True
        self._thread = thread_object(target=self.run)                
        self._thread.start()            

    def run(self):
        while(self._is_to_run):
            self.new_image = self._capture.update()


cam = Camera()
cam.start()

while True:
    image = cam.new_image
    result = do_some_process_image(image)
```

Is this safe?

Comment: Protect from what?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [ask]. Could you give us the code that you have, what you're expecting, and what you're seeing instead?

Comment: I thought the question was clear. There is no need for code.

Comment: The question is far from clear. What threat are you imagining? What environment are you operating in? What requirements do you have for reliability and security?

Comment: Please see the edited question. I'm talking about a parallel process using the threading module in python,

Comment: What data protection mechanisms are you talking about?

Comment: How would you protect a file from being... read, I guess? BTW, you can use mutexes in Python just like you do in C++.

Comment: Ok, let me write some pseudo-code to illustrate my question.

Comment: Hope it is clear now.

Comment: @Alex why would you think he's a new user... He has reputation...

Comment: Good, you post the code.

Comment: As you can see. the text perfectly illustrates the bit of basic pseudo-code I wrote, but I understand that the code does make it a bit simpler to understand. 
But we programmers must always remain humble and realize that what we know is a infinitesimal fraction of all there is to know, no matter of how much experience we have. So, sometimes we should refrain from voting to close a question just because we didn't immediately grasp the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of al, the `threading` module uses threads, *not* different processes!

The crucial difference between threads and processes is that the former share an address space (memory), while the latter don't.

The "standard" python implementation (CPython) uses a Global Interpreter Lock to ensure that only one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode. So for data that can be updated with one one bytecode instruction (like `store_fast`) you *might* not need mutexes. When a thread that is modifying such a variable is interrupted, either the store has been done or it hasn't.

But *in general* you definitely need to protect data structures from reading and modification by multiple threads. If a thread is interrupted while it is in the proces of modifying say a large dictionary and execution is passed to another thread that tries to read from the dictionary, it might find the data in an inconsistant state.

Comment: Yes, when I say processes, I do not mean actual processes with different ID's in the system, but different routines. I admit that it may lead to confusion. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python *shouldn't* segfault in situations like this - the [global intepreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) is your friend. However, even in your example there's every chance that a camera interface is going to go into some random C library that doesn't necessarily behave itself. Even then, it doesn't prevent all race conditions in your code and you could easily find inconsistent data because of that.

Python does have [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) which is very low-level and doesn't provide much functionality. [`Condition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition) is a higher-level type that is better for implementing a mutex-like lock:

```
# Consume one item
with cv:
    while not an_item_is_available():
        cv.wait()
    get_an_available_item()

# Produce one item
with cv:
    make_an_item_available()
    cv.notify()
```

Incidentally, there was a [`mutex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mutex.html) in Python 2, which was deprecated in 2.6 and removed in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is is the lock Object -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects

> A primitive lock is a synchronization primitive that is not owned by a
>   particular thread when locked. In Python, it is currently the lowest
>   level synchronization primitive available, implemented directly by the
>   thread extension module.

In your example, I would encapsulate the access  to the image in a function like this

```
def image_access(self, image_Data = None):
    lock = Lock()
    lock.acquire()
    temp = self.new_image
    try:
        if image_Data not None:
            self.new_image = image_Data
    finally:
        lock.release()
    if image_Data is None:
        return temp
```

For more on Thread synchronization, see -> http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

Edit:

Here are the cahnges to the ohter functions

```
def run(self):
    while(self._is_to_run):
        self.image_access(self._capture.update())

...

while True:
    result = do_some_process_image(cam.image_access())
```